# ¿Cómo leer y escribir archivos utilizando FILE por referencia en C++?

Tags: c++, archivo

Tengo que leer y escribir un archivo utilizando FILE por referencia.

```
    struct usuario {
        int id;
        string nombre;
        string apellido;
    };

    usuario usuarios[50];

    // Creo un array de 1 registro para luego guardarlo en un archivo .dat
    usuarios[0].id = 1;
    usuarios[0].nombre = "Roberto";
    usuarios[0].apellido = "Calani";
```

Hasta el momento tengo solo eso de codigo, pero quiero que al momento de leer mi archivo utilizar ese struct y poder utilizar todos los registros del archivo.

```
FILE * usuario; 
usuario = fopen("usuarios.dat", "rb");
```

Aca le asigne el struct para luego poder leer `usuario.id`, `usuario.nombre` y `usuario.apellido`. (No se como todavia, pero entiendo eso)

Pero mi duda es como leo y como escribo un archivo utilizando struct y FILE por referencia? Tengo entendido que se guarda en un archivo (usuaios.dat) y este archivo esta en binario que por ende al momento de querer abrirlo con un bloc de notas, este seria ilegible.

Se poco y nada de c++ pero la lógica la entiendo mas o menos ya que manejo php y js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, te falta conocer en mayor profundidad el objeto `FILE`.

#### Nociones básicas de [`std::FILE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c).

En realidad `std::FILE` es un puntero que obtiene un valor diferente de nulo cuando se abre un archivo mediante la función [`std::fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen), para leer y escribir deberás usar las funciones [`std::fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) y [`std::fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) respectivamente o [`std::fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) y [`std::fprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) si quieres leer con formato; todas estas funciones esperan recibir un puntero a `std::FILE` para operar sobre el mismo.

#### Leer del archivo.

Veo en tu código que abres un archivo en el modo lectura (*read* `"r"`) binaria (*binary* `"b"`):

```
FILE * usuario = fopen("usuarios.dat", "rb");
```

Así que la función de lectura a usar será `std::fread`, que recibe cuatro parámetros:

1. Dirección de memoria donde leer.
2. Tamaño de los datos a leer.
3. Cantidad de datos a leer.
4. Puntero a `std::FILE` del que leer.

Por lo tanto, para leer tu estructura necesitarás:

1. Un entero (`int`) temporal sobre el que leer datos numéricos.
2. Un búfer de caracteres temporal sobre el que leer datos de texto.

Asumiendo que antes del nombre y del apellido hayas guardado la longitud de cada uno de ellos, tu proceso de lectura podría parecerse a:

```
int i;
char c[200]{};
usuario u;
std::FILE *f = fopen("usuarios.dat", "rb");

// Leemos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
std::fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f);
u.id = i;

// Leemos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
std::fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'nombre'
// Leemos en 'c' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' desde 'f'.
std::fread(c, sizeof(char), i, f); // 'nombre'
u.nombre = c;

// Leemos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
std::fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'apellido'
// Leemos en 'c' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' desde 'f'.
std::fread(c, sizeof(char), i, f); // 'apellido'
u.apellido = c;
```

#### Escribir en el archivo.

Deberás abrir el archivo en el modo escritura (*write* `"w"`) binaria (*binary* `"b"`) (por coherencia con lo anterior):

```
FILE * usuario = fopen("usuarios.dat", "wb");
```

Así que la función de lectura a usar será `std::fwrite`, que recibe cuatro parámetros:

1. Dirección de los datos que escribir.
2. Tamaño de los datos a escribir.
3. Cantidad de datos a escribir.
4. Puntero a `std::FILE` en el que escribir.

Por lo tanto, para escribir tu estructura necesitarás:

1. Un entero (`int`) desde el que se escribirán datos numéricos.

Tu proceso de escritura podría parecerse a:

```
int i;
usuario u;
std::FILE *f = fopen("usuarios.dat", "wb");

// Escribimos un dato de tamaño 'int' en 'f'.
std::fwrite(&u.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);

// Escribimos un dato de tamaño 'int' en 'f'.
i = nombre.length();
std::fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'nombre'
// Escribimos desde 'nombre.data()' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' en 'f'.
std::fread(nombre.data(), sizeof(char), i, f); // 'nombre'

// Escribimos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
i = apellido.length();
std::fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'apellido'
// Escribimos desde 'apellido.data()' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' en 'f'.
std::fwrite(c, sizeof(char), i, f); // 'apellido'
```

#### Todo junto: por referencia.

Lo adecuado sería que las operaciones de lectura y escritura estuvieran encapsuladas en una función propia:

```
void leer_dato(usuario &u, std::FILE *&f)
{
    int i;
    char c[200]{};

    // Leemos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
    std::fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    u.id = i;

    // Leemos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
    std::fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'nombre'
    // Leemos en 'c' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' desde 'f'.
    std::fread(c, sizeof(char), i, f); // 'nombre'
    u.nombre = c;

    // Leemos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
    std::fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'apellido'
    // Leemos en 'c' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' desde 'f'.
    std::fread(c, sizeof(char), i, f); // 'apellido'
    u.apellido = c;
}

void escribir_dato(const usuario &u, std::FILE *&f)
{
    int i;

    // Escribimos un dato de tamaño 'int' en 'f'.
    std::fwrite(&u.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);

    // Escribimos un dato de tamaño 'int' en 'f'.
    i = nombre.length();
    std::fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'nombre'
    // Escribimos desde 'nombre.data()' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' en 'f'.
    std::fread(nombre.data(), sizeof(char), i, f); // 'nombre'

    // Escribimos en 'i' un dato de tamaño 'int' desde 'f'.
    i = apellido.length();
    std::fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f); // Longitud de 'apellido'
    // Escribimos desde 'apellido.data()' 'i' datos de tamaño 'char' en 'f'.
    std::fwrite(c, sizeof(char), i, f); // 'apellido'
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

El objeto `std::FILE` pertenece a las librerías de C, dado que has etiquetado la pregunta como C++, **olvídalo y no lo uses**. Usa los flujos (*stream*) de datos `std::ifstream` y `std::ofstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira pues generalmente los datos binarios se tratan con la clase fstream de esta forma:

```
ifstream fichero( "usuarios.bin", ios::binary );
```

Ten cuenta que la codificacion depende del so en el cual trabajes, incluso del compilador que uses, por lo que si no tienes cuidado en especial con los saltos de linea, tendras un dolor de cabeza extra.

En tu caso el codigo quedaría algo así:

```
if ( fichero.is_open() ) 
     {
       fichero.read( (char *) &usuarios, sizeof( usuario ) );
       while( !fichero.eof() ) {
       volcar( cout,usuarios );
       fichero.read( (char *) &usuarios, sizeof( usuario ) );
     }
else 
     {
        cout << "Error de apertura de archivo." << endl;
     }
```

Hace rato que no toco c++ y la verdad es que desconozco el uso de FILE en estos casos. Es todo lo que puedo ayudarte por ahora amigo.